# Hypothesis testing for inaccurate sampling

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

My problem is as follows:

Imagine a set of points, their positions have been recorded with a rubbish GPS, so are not precise and have a high error (assume no systematic error). Call this set $I$ (inaccurate).
A surveyor goes out with a very good GPS and records exact locations (assume no error) for these points (but might miss some, and might capture some that were missed in $I$), this is set $A$ (accurate).

Explicitly, a matching of points from $I$ to $A$ is a bijection from some subset $I_0$ of $I$ to a subset $A_0$ of $A$.

Assuming the error in sampling the points in $A$ has known distribution (let's assume normal), I'd like to find a maximally sized matching of points from $I$ to $A$ with 95% confidence that this is correct.

I have an algorithm to find plausible matchings, but am unsure how to compute the confidence that they are correct. My statistics knowledge is limited, but this sounds like hypothesis testing to me.

Here is my attempt:

1. Fix some plausible matching, $f$, from $I$ to $A$ say defined on $I_0$ with image $A_0$.
2. Let $H_0$ be the hypothesis: "This is an incorrect matching". Let $H_1$ be the hypothesis: "This is a correct matching".
3. Assume the sampling errors in $R$ are normally distributed with variance $1$ and independent.

Here's where I start to struggle. I'm not sure which statistical test or test statistic to use, I think the test statistic I'd want to will be somehow related to $t = \sum \limits_{i \in I_0} |f(i) - i|^2$, i.e. the squared sum of the distances from the inaccurate points to the points. This makes me think the chi-squared test would be useful?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your $H_0$ is not a statistical hypothesis because it does not correspond to a definite distribution of any statistic. In fact, you seem to be using "confidence" in a different sense, perhaps meaning "probability of being correct." In general $95\%$ is *far* too high a standard to aim for. In circumstances with large numbers of good candidate matches for each surveyed point you can't even hope to attain $50\%$ per point--and those numbers have to be multiplied in each such case, which could result in an astronomically low chance that any particular matching is *the* correct one.

Comment: Sorry hit post too soon. Is there a better technique? I can find likely matchings but I want to take one which is very likely to be correct.

Comment: You could compare your $t$ to $\textrm{Normal}\left(0,|A_0|\right)$ to see if the $I_0\sim A_0$ matching is consistent with the $\textrm{Normal}(0,1)$ model for errors but, as *whuber* points out, that can't tell you which is "the" correct matching.  But perhaps a greedy approach will be good enough.  Use the Munkres algorithm to find the $I\sim A$ assignment minimising the mean squared error: call that mean $E_1$.  Throw away the worst $a\in A$ and $i \in I$ from the matching, re-run, get $E_2$.  Repeat.  Plot the E's.  The winning matching is the first where that and all later E are "small".

Comment: ... but definitely look at the plot, don't just set a "small" threshold and run the algorithm blindly.  If the plot exhibits an elbow before the "small E's" region, that might be a hint that you've genuinely got a good matching.  If it doesn't, it's a hint that my greedy Munkres suggestion was codswallop.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach creosote. I'm away this week but will try and implement it when I get back. Thanks for your input